# Datasnap inheriting servermethods. and using them through different client applications

Tags: delphi, inheritance, delphi-xe5, datasnap

I create 3 datasnap servers that all connect to the same database, and use the same login procedure.

My first thought is that i should inherit my servermethods from a base servermethod class that has a login procedure. see pseudo code :

```
tsimplemethods
procedure login:virtual

tserver1 = class(tsimplemethods)
procedure doseomething

tserver2 = class(tsimplemethods)
procedure dosomethingelse
```

This works and i can generate datasnap clientmethods for the 2 servers.
The problem is when i want to use the login procedure in a login unit that i want to use for 3 different client applications that connect to 3 different servers with the same login procedure. pseudo code :

```
unit login
procedure login
var
  tmpM:tsimplemethodsclient
begin
  tmpM.login;
end;
```

but this gives exception that TSimpleservermethods.login is not exposed on the Server.
It does work if i do in in the client for 1 of the servers. for example:

```
unit client1
procedure login
var
  tmpM:TServer1Methods;
begin
  tmpM.login;
end;
```

I was thinking that the login unit should know wich Servermethods to use. maybe through an event or using Template class for login.

*** EDIT : *** possible workaround : i have changed the ServerMethodClient to incorporate a ServerClassname that i can change to a derived serverclass.

```
procedure TSimpleServerMethodsClient.Login();
begin
  if FPW_LoginCommand = nil then
  begin
    FPW_LoginCommand := FDBXConnection.CreateCommand;
    FPW_LoginCommand.CommandType := TDBXCommandTypes.DSServerMethod;
//I changed this
    FPW_LoginCommand.Text := MyServerClassname+'.Login'; 
// instead of 'TSimpleserverMethods.login
    FPW_LoginCommand.Prepare;
  end;

  FPW_LoginCommand.ExecuteUpdate;   


end;
```

This seems to work.

Comment: Just a thought. IMHO you should better *separate your concerns*, i.e. let authentication/authorization been made by one service, i.e. one class, then process done by another services. The authentication services may return a "token" after login (or a session ID), then you just pass this token to other services. Most of the time, I prefer [composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance), and use inheritance only when I want to share some common code. Your design will break the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle

Comment: Thnx for the reply, i have found a work around. The problem lies with how datasnap is designed to call servermethods. when invoking a servermethod it will give the classname+servermethod.